# How to scrape only one price?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to scrape product prices from a website and both real price and the monthly payment quota value has exactly the same class, so I can't figure it out how to only get main price.

[image: Page description]

and this is for the main price: "879.990"
this is for the monthly payment quota: "39.990",

this is the URL: [https://listado.mercadolibre.cl/macbook#D[A:macbook]](https://listado.mercadolibre.cl/macbook#D%5BA:macbook%5D)

```
#THIS GETS ALL THE NAMES AND STORES IT IN A LIST

prod = soup.find_all('h2', class_ ='ui-search-item__title shops__item-title') 

productos = list()
count=0
for i in prod:
    if count < 33:
        productos.append(i.text)
    else:
        break
        count +=1
size= len(productos) +1
#print(size)
#print(productos, len(productos))
print(productos)

#THIS GETS ALL THE NAMES AND STORES IT IN A LIST

pri = soup.find_all('span',class_ ="price-tag-fraction")
precios = list()
count=0
for i in pri:
    if count < 33:
        precios.append(i.text)
     
    else:
        break
        count +=1
#rint(precios)
prices= [item.split(',')for item in precios]
```

Here is the output
[image: output]

Comment: Hard to believe they're the exact same class, since they are quite different in appearance.

Comment: right but both prices has the same class wich is 'span',class_ ="price-tag-fraction"

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the other prices [using CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```py
# filsel = 'span.price-tag-fraction:not(span.ui-search-installments span):not(s.price-tag__disabled span)'
emiSp_sel = 'span.ui-search-installments span' # monthly
disab_sel = 's.price-tag__disabled span' # crossed out
filsel = f'span.price-tag-fraction:not({emiSp_sel}):not({disab_sel})'

pri = [p.get_text() for p in soup.select(filsel)]
```

or using [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) with `find`

```py
pri = soup.find_all(
    lambda p: p.name == 'span' and 'price-tag-fraction' in p.get('class', '')
    and p.find_parent('span', {'class': 'ui-search-installments'}) is None
    and p.find_parent('s', {'class': 'price-tag__disabled'}) is None
)
```

or even by combining [lists comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) with your current method

```py
pri = [
    p for p in soup.find_all('span',class_ ="price-tag-fraction") 
    if p.find_parent('span', {'class': 'ui-search-installments'}) is None
    and p.find_parent('s', {'class': 'price-tag__disabled'}) is None
]
```